# Ошибка при создании таблицы с помощью миграции laravel

Tags: laravel

Создаю таблицу, для связи с помощью Foreign, выдаёт такую ошибку. В чём причина?

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `test-laravel`.`posts` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `posts` add constraint `posts_ndepart_foreign` foreign key (`ndepart`) references `departments` (`id`))

  at C:\Users\Николай\Documents\test-laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:665
    661|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    662|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    663|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    664|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 665|             throw new QueryException(
    666|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    667|             );
    668|         }
    669|

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `test-laravel`.`posts` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")")
      C:\Users\Николай\Documents\test-laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:459

  2   PDOStatement::execute()
      C:\Users\Николай\Documents\test-laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:459

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

Таблицы:
posts - https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGu1a.png
departments - https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbjHj.png

Comment: покажите обе таблицы - departments и posts

Comment: Добавил ссылки на скрины таблиц, посмотрите пожалуйста.

Comment: Вы пытаетесь связать поле типа BIGINT с полем типа INT - отсюда и ошибка.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.